# Sum progression in an array Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sum

I have an basic `Int array`

```
Array = [8, 9, 8]
```

How do i sum all of its values progressively so that the end result would look like this

```
EndResult = [8, 17, 25]
```

Tried using for and while loops, but to no avail.

NB: Basic `array[0] + array[1]` advices will not work. I'm looking for something automatic like a loop solution.

Looking forward to your advices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be this:

```
var arr = [8, 9, 8]

for i in 1..<arr.count {
    arr[i] += arr[i-1]
}

print(arr)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Probably there are better ways than this one, but it works

```
var array = [8, 9, 8]
var result = [Int]()
for i in 0..<array.count{
    var temp = 0;
    for j in 0...i{
        temp+=array[j]
    }
    result.append(temp)
}
print(result) //[8, 17, 25]
```

Comment: @Alexander yea, as I said, there are better solutions than this one

Answer (score 1):

You could use a reduce function in Swift to accomplish this.  Note that you can't really do it with map, because you would need to know what the previous call to the map function returned, keep state in a variable outside the map function (which seems dirty), or loop over your array for every map function call.

```
    let array = [8, 9, 8]
    let results = array.reduce((0, []), combine: { (reduction: (lastValue: Int, values: Array<Int>), value: Int) in
        let newValue = reduction.lastValue + value
        return (newValue, reduction.values + [newValue])
    }).1
```